# Excel gets incomplete line from CSV

Tags: excel, csv

Excel displays the following line incomplete :
Actual line:

```
"- Guides students through the new course and assessment structure with advice at the start of the book to help them understand what's required- Enables students to put their knowledge in context and helps them start analysing business data with case studies of real businesses included throughout- Prepares students for assessment with the 'Your turn' feature that contains practice questions including multiple choice, case study and data response, and those that test their quantitative skills"
```

Excel Displaying the incomplete line

```
- Guides students through the new course and assessment structure with advice at the start of the book to help them understand what's required- Enables students to put their knowledge in context and helps them start analysing business data with case studi
```

Please help

REgards

Kris

Comment: You'll need to add more information. What delimiters are in use? any strange looking characters between `i` and `e` in the word `studies`?

Comment: The incomplete line is 255 characters long.  Seems like a hint ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is apparently a bug in Excel.

Because the text has a leading dash `"-"`, Excel first tries to parse it as a number which is limited to 255 characters, but when that fails and it switches back to General, it never restores the text to the 32767 character limit.

See this answer at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/542927/increase-size-limit-of-data-import-from-csv-into-excel) for a more thorough answer and a workaround.

A workaround is to avoid having a leading dash.  The fix is to declare the column as "Text" instead of "General" in the CSV Importer.

Comment: Most likely this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (not about programming), and definitely on-topic for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @BigBen SO does also allow questions about development environments and development tools and Excel counts as both (this was established here at least 12 years ago).  So just as SO allows questions about web sites, deployments, and databases, it also allows question like this for Excel.  I agree that SuperUser is probably a better site (just as http://www.dba.stackexchange.com would be for 80% of the SQL questions asked here), but it is still allowed here. As it is already answered here, and disruptive and confusing to users to move their questions , I think it best to leave this one here.

Comment: Fine - you are entitled to that opinion, but I have still voted to close as not suitable for this site. Really, I should have voted for it to be migrated to Super User. But whatevs.